# How can I get the text of an element, excluding certain tags

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a phrase hyphenated (separated by syllables) with dashes. I found [this page](https://poemas-del-alma.com/metrica.php), and it hyphenates very good, but with slashes, adds a slash after every word and **the quantity of syllables of every line after each of them**. I [injected](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/code-injector/fehfokkkkeamcfiaogfdkkpoblipkmbd) some [code](https://codepen.io/luisgallego/pen/PowPmpz) to the page to get the text from the results and replace "/ " with " " and then "/" with "-", and then print it on `textarea` , but I get every few words a "= x syllables" message, and I need it without it. I see these messages are inside a `strong` tag, so I was wondering if there was a way to get all the text from the result, excepting the text inside `strong` tags.

**Tl;dr**: I need to get

> Hello, world!Hello, world!Hello, world!

from this:

```
<div id="text">
 <div>
  Hello, world!
 </div>
  Hello, world!
 <div>
  Hello, world!
 </div>
 <span>
  Not this
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your [mcve] code in your question, don’t just link to it.

Comment: This question is confusing...Main objective is to hyphenate text found in HTML? A result of 4 cannot be correct for the number of syllables found in example (If omitting the last sentence there are 9 syllables). I believe 4 is the number of lines of text or elements that contain text. The result you provided doesn't have any hyphens at all...The example HTML doesn't have a `<strong>` element... Basically you just want certain text from HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a page like an API provider using injections. You may succeed what you want, but the right way to do it is to actually make it by searching for solutions, create some logic and then write some code to do what you want.

If you just want to extract the text and exclude certain tags without white-spaces, then use DOM `querySelectorAll` to match what you want and exclude what you don't want with a selector like this `#text :not(span)`, then map the `textContent` and finally remove white-spaces with a regular expression like this `replace(/\s/g, '')`:

```js
var result = [...document.querySelectorAll('#text :not(span)')]
  .map(e => e.textContent)
  .join()
  .replace(/\s/g, '');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="text">
 <div>
  Hello, world!
 </div>  
 <div>
  Hello, world!
 </div>
 <div>
  Hello, world!
 </div>
 
 <span>
  Not this
 </span>
</div>
```

Now, if you want to create your own, then you'd find the very popular [compromise](https://github.com/spencermountain/compromise) package with the [syllables](https://github.com/spencermountain/compromise/tree/master/plugins/syllables) plugin that you can use like this:

```js
nlp.extend(compromiseSyllables);

function convert() {
  // Get textarea text
  const text = document.getElementById('text').value;

  // Create npl document with the text
  const doc = nlp(text);

  // Get syllables array using npl syllables plugin
  const syllables = doc.terms().syllables();

  // Create the wanted string result using the syllables array
  const result = syllables.map(({ syllables }) => syllables.join('-')).join(' ');

  // Output the result
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = result;
}

convert();

document.getElementById('convert').onclick = convert;

// result =>
// as se-cond ar-gu-ment e-mo-ji-fy takes an han-dler to par-se un-known e-mo-jis
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/compromise"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/compromise-syllables"></script>

<textarea id="text" cols="50" rows="5">
As second argument, emojify takes an handler to parse unknown emojis
</textarea>

<div>
  <button id="convert">Convert</button>
</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain JS/DOM API style:

```js
const nodes = document.getElementById("text").childNodes;
let buffer = [];

for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    let node = nodes[i];

    if ((node.nodeName !== "SPAN") && node.textContent.trim().length !== 0) {
        buffer.push(node.textContent.trim()); 
    }
}

let result = buffer.join("");

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="text">
 <div>
  Hello, world!
 </div>
  Hello, world!
 <div>
  Hello, world!
 </div>
 <span>
  Not this
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using VanillaJS:

```js
var clonetext = document.getElementById("text").cloneNode(true);

clonetext.querySelectorAll("*:not(div)").forEach(function(v){v.remove()});

console.log(clonetext.innerText);
```

```html
<div id="text">
 <div>
  Hello, world!
 </div>
  Hello, world!
 <div>
  Hello, world!
 </div>
 <span>
  Not this
 </span>
 <a>Not this</a>
</div>
```

Use cloneNode function and do create new DOMCollection from `#text`

Remove all childs except divs

Get innerText of `#text`